# How to use create statement and select statement in a single java action class

Tags: java, sql, struts2

In my application I really want to execute `create` statement and `select` statement in a single `execute()` method(struts 2)

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME 1(SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 2)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 1
```

How can i do this ? please help me.

Comment: IMHO, isn't possible. They are two different statement. The first is DDL, the second DML. Concern the DBMS used you can created a table starting from a SELECT statement (but this in another thing)

Comment: only Chuck Norris can make this thing happen

Comment: What ORM you are using